# Ember.js bind class change on click

Tags: ember.js

How do i change an elements class on click via ember.js, AKA:

```
<div class="row" {{bindAttr class="isEnabled:enabled:disabled"}}>
```

View:

```
SearchDropdown.SearchResultV = Ember.View.extend(Ember.Metamorph, {
    isEnabled: false,

    click: function(){
        window.alert(true);
        this.isEnabled = true;
    }
});
```

The click event works as window alert happens, I just cant get the binding to.

Comment: With ember properties, you'll want to do `this.set('isEnabled', true);`

Comment: @pauldechov that's correct. You should add it as an answer.

Comment: @LukeMelia added. By the way, what is the purpose of having Ember.Metamorph here?

Comment: Adding `Ember.Metamorph` is useful in large data handling - makes ember act like an `each` helper instead of a `collection`, therefore much quicker

Answer (score 5):

The class is bound correctly, but the `isEnabled` property should be modified only with a `.set` call such as `this.set('isEnabled', true)` and accessed only with `this.get('isEnabled')`. This is an Ember convention in support of first-class bindings and computed properties.

Answer (score 2):

In your view you will bind to a className. I have the following view in my app:

```
EurekaJ.TabItemView = Ember.View.extend(Ember.TargetActionSupport, {
    content: null,
    tagName: 'li',

    classNameBindings: "isSelected",

    isSelected: function() {
        return this.get('controller').get('selectedTab').get('tabId') == this.get('tab').get('tabId');
    }.property('controller.selectedTab'),

    click: function() {
        this.get('controller').set('selectedTab', this.get('tab'));
        if (this.get('tab').get('tabState')) {
            EurekaJ.router.transitionTo(this.get('tab').get('tabState'));
        }

    },

    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('<div class="featureTabTop"></div>{{tab.tabName}}')
});
```

Here, you have bound your className to whatever the "isSelected" property returns. This is only true if the views' controller's selected tab ID is the same as this views' tab ID.

The code will append a CSS class name of "is-selected" when the view is selected.

If you want to see the code in context, the code is on GitHub: https://github.com/joachimhs/EurekaJ/blob/netty-ember/EurekaJ.View/src/main/webapp/js/app/views.js#L100

Answer (score 1):

Good answers, however I went down a different route:

```
SearchDropdown.SearchResultV = Ember.View.extend(Ember.Metamorph, {
    classNameBindings: ['isSelected'],
    click: function(){

        var content = this.get('content');
        SearchDropdown.SelectedSearchController.set('content', content);
        var loadcontent = this.get('content');
        loadcontent.set("searchRadius", $("select[name=radius]").val());

        SearchDropdown.LoadMap.load(content);

    },
    isSelected: function () {
        var selectedItem = SearchDropdown.SelectedSearchController.get('content'),
          content = this.get('content');
        if (content === selectedItem) {
          return true;
        }
      }.property('SearchDropdown.SelectedSearchController.content')
});
```

Controller:

```
SearchDropdown.SelectedSearchController = Ember.Object.create({
  content: null,

});
```

Basically stores the data of the selected view in a controller,